# NUXT.JS WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9090/5' failed

Tags: websocket, nuxt.js

I'm currently developing a NUXT application, everything works as should but when viewing the console log I'm getting the following error 'WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9090/5' failed' the error is constantly repeating and the console log is racking up to 1,517+ messages. There doesn't seem to be much online to fix this issue. If anyone knows how to resolve I'd greatly appreciate the help.

[image]

Comment: Is your server running? Are you sure your configuration is correct? Do you have some code to share?